# Tabularx, landscape, \toprule \midrule do not fully underline row

Tags: tabularx, landscape, booktabs

Somehow `\toprule` does not underline the whole row of my table. Hopefully, someone can explain to me what I am doing wrong. My ultimate goal is to create a table similar to:[image: Snippit of ANDREY GOLUBOV, DIMITRIS PETMEZAS, and NICKOLAOS G. TRAVLOS paper, When It Pays to Pay Your Investment Banker, 2012]

Copy of my shortened code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{lscape}
        \begin{landscape}
    {
    \def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
    \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{l*{4}{lccc}}
    \toprule
                        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Full sample (1)}  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Top 50\% experience target ind. (2)}  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Bottem 50\% Experience target ind(3)}  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(2-3)}           \\
                        &\multicolumn{2}{c}{}     &\multicolumn{2}{c}{}     &\multicolumn{2}{c}{}     &\multicolumn{2}{c}{}              \\
                        &        mean&          sd&        mean&          sd&        mean&          sd&           b         &           t\\
    \midrule
    Book to Market       &       2.911&      18.792&       3.341&      16.830&       2.642&      19.949&      -0.699         &    (-0.371)\\
    Free cash flow      &     225.883&    4275.873&     325.020&    6726.092&     163.922&    1242.414&    -161.098         &    (-0.290)\\
    Leverage            &       0.578&       0.204&       0.601&       0.206&       0.564&       0.202&      -0.037         &    (-1.734)\\
    Relative size       &      87.852&     667.603&      50.216&     184.712&     111.334&     838.031&      61.119         &     (1.075)\\
    \midrule
    Observations        &         390&            &         150&            &         240&            &         390         &            \\
    \bottomrule
    \end{tabularx}
    }
    \end{landscape}
```

Good to mention is that the code is created using the STATA package esstab + booktabs.

Comment: `\textwidth` on a landscape page eould equal the width of a line of text in a portrait page. To get the width of a line of text in a landscape page, you can use `\linewidth` instead. Apart from that, a `tabularx` at least needs one `X` type column. I don't see any `X` type columns in your code, so don't use `tabularx`.

Comment: @leandriis thanks! Changed to \linewidth solved it. Indeed, the X is missing. Thanks for the catch and comments.

Comment: I have edited the title of your question since the commands from `booktabs` are called `...rule` instead of `...line`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I understand that the table is automatically generated, but after that you *need* to fix it so it's readable and syntactically sound. For instance, `tabularx` here is completely useless, because no `X` column is specified.

Here's a reworking using `siunitx` and some tricks to reduce the header widths.

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{rotating}

\newcommand{\splitcell}[2][c]{\begin{tabular}[#1]{@{}c@{}}#2\end{tabular}}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\centering

\sisetup{% we don't need to parse uncertainty
  input-open-uncertainty={},
  input-close-uncertainty={}
}

\caption{Some caption to the table}

\begin{tabular}{
  @{}
  l
  S[table-format=3.3]
  S[table-format=4.3]
  S[table-format=3.3]
  S[table-format=4.3]
  S[table-format=3.3]
  S[table-format=4.3]
  S[table-format=-3.3]
  S[table-format=-1.3,
    table-space-text-pre={(},
    table-space-text-post={)},
    table-align-text-pre=false
  ]
  @{}
}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{Full sample (1)}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\splitcell[t]{Top 50\% \\ experience \\ target ind. (2)}}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{\splitcell[t]{Bottom 50\% \\ experience \\ target ind. (3)}}
& \multicolumn{2}{c}{$(3)-(2)$}
\\
\cmidrule(lr){2-3}\cmidrule(lr){4-5}\cmidrule(lr){6-7}\cmidrule(l){8-9}
& {mean} & {sd} & {mean} & {sd} & {mean} & {sd} & {b} & {t} \\
\midrule
Book to Market &   2.911 &   18.792 &   3.341 &   16.830 &   2.642 &   19.949 &   -0.699 & (-0.371)\\
Free cash flow & 225.883 & 4275.873 & 325.020 & 6726.092 & 163.922 & 1242.414 & -161.098 & (-0.290)\\
Leverage       &   0.578 &    0.204 &   0.601 &    0.206 &   0.564 &    0.202 &   -0.037 & (-1.734)\\
Relative size  &  87.852 &  667.603 &  50.216 &  184.712 & 111.334 &  838.031 &   61.119 &  (1.075)\\
\midrule
Observations   &  {390}  &          &   {150} &          &  {240}  &          &    {390} &         \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1. I think it would be a good idea (not implemented by the OP, but good nevertheless...) to replace the final header, `(2-3)`, with `$(2)-(3)$` or, better yet, `$(3)-(2)$`, as the numbers in the `b` column are merely the differences of the numbers in the two preceding `mean` columns.

Comment: @Mico Suggestion implemented

Answer (score 3):

In the following example, I have removed the `tabularx` and in order to make the table fit into the page, I have introduced linebreaks in the headers. I have also added the `\cmidrule`s and removed the unnecessary columns (in the original you declared a total of 17 columns but only used 9). In the second table I have added `siunitx` to improve the alignment of the numbers in the table.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{pdflscape}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\begin{landscape}
\centering
\def\sym#1{\ifmmode^{#1}\else\(^{#1}\)\fi}
\begin{tabular}{l*{2}{lccc}}
\toprule
                    &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Full sample (1)}  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Top 50\%\\ experience target \\ind. (2)}}  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Bottom 50\%\\ Experience target\\ ind(3)}}  &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(2-3)}           \\
          \cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9}
                    &        mean&          sd&        mean&          sd&        mean&          sd&           b         &           t\\
\midrule
Book to Market       &       2.911&      18.792&       3.341&      16.830&       2.642&      19.949&      -0.699         &    (-0.371)\\
Free cash flow      &     225.883&    4275.873&     325.020&    6726.092&     163.922&    1242.414&    -161.098         &    (-0.290)\\
Leverage            &       0.578&       0.204&       0.601&       0.206&       0.564&       0.202&      -0.037         &    (-1.734)\\
Relative size       &      87.852&     667.603&      50.216&     184.712&     111.334&     838.031&      61.119         &     (1.075)\\
\midrule
Observations        &         390&            &         150&            &         240&            &         390         &            \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}

\bigskip

\begin{tabular}{l
                *{3}{
                S[table-format=3.3]
                S[table-format=4.3]}
                S[table-format=-3.3]
                S[table-format=-1.3,
                  input-open-uncertainty= ,
                  input-close-uncertainty  = ,
                  table-space-text-pre={(}, 
                  table-space-text-post={)},
                  table-align-text-pre = false]
           }
\toprule
     &\multicolumn{2}{c}{Full sample (1)}  
         &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Top 50\%\\ experience target \\ind. (2)}}  
             &\multicolumn{2}{c}{\makecell{Bottom 50\%\\ Experience target\\ ind(3)}}  
                 &\multicolumn{2}{c}{(2-3)}           \\
          \cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9}
    &        {mean}&          {sd}
        &        {mean}&          {sd}
            &        {mean}&          {sd}
                &           {b}         &           {t}\\
\midrule
Book to Market       &       2.911&      18.792&       3.341&      16.830&       2.642&      19.949&      -0.699         &    (-0.371)\\
Free cash flow      &     225.883&    4275.873&     325.020&    6726.092&     163.922&    1242.414&    -161.098         &    (-0.290)\\
Leverage            &       0.578&       0.204&       0.601&       0.206&       0.564&       0.202&      -0.037         &    (-1.734)\\
Relative size       &      87.852&     667.603&      50.216&     184.712&     111.334&     838.031&      61.119         &     (1.075)\\
\midrule
Observations        &         {390}&            &         {150}&            &         {240}&            &         {390}         &            \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's a solution that continues the use of a `tabularx` environment.

I've reduced the total number of columns to `9` and have assigned a centered version of the `X` column type to all 8 data columns. I've also used several `\cmidrule` directives to provide more visual structure to the header material. Observe that by allowing line breaks in the header cells, it becomes much easier to fit the entire table in landscape format.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2.5cm]{geometry} % set suitable page parameters
\usepackage{booktabs,tabularx,ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{C}{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\doublehsize{\hsize=\dimexpr2\hsize+2\tabcolsep\relax} % handy shortcut macro
\usepackage{rotating}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{} l *{8}{C} @{}}
\toprule
&\multicolumn{2}{>{\doublehsize}C}{Full sample (1)}  
&\multicolumn{2}{>{\doublehsize}C}{Top 50\% experience target ind.~(2)}  
&\multicolumn{2}{>{\doublehsize}C}{Bottom 50\% experience target ind.~(3)}  
&\multicolumn{2}{>{\doublehsize}C}{$(2)-(3)$} \\

\cmidrule(lr){2-3} \cmidrule(lr){4-5} \cmidrule(lr){6-7} \cmidrule(l){8-9}
 & mean & sd & mean & sd & mean & sd & b & t\\
\midrule
Book to Market  &   2.911&   18.792&   3.341&   16.830&   2.642&   19.949&   $-0.699$ & ($-0.371$)\\
Free cash flow  & 225.883& 4275.873& 325.020& 6726.092& 163.922& 1242.414& $-161.098$ & ($-0.290$)\\
Leverage        &   0.578&    0.204&   0.601&    0.206&   0.564&    0.202&   $-0.037$ & ($-1.734$)\\
Relative size   &  87.852&  667.603&  50.216&  184.712& 111.334&  838.031&   $61.119$ &  ($1.075$)\\
\midrule
Observations    &  390 &  &  150 &  &  240 &  &  390      & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```